# Unable to Populate Values from REST API using ng-repeat in Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, spring

I am making an Rest call from Angular JS. once i get the response from the API . I am planning to Populate Messages on the Front end using ng-repeat .This is my controller side call .

```
     $http({
          url: "http://localhost:8080/services/AddConfig", 
          method: "POST",
          data: dataobj,
          headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
         }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                responseData = data;
                $scope.dbresponse = responseData;
                console.log(responseData);
                console.log($scope.dbresponse[0].messages);
                console.log($scope.dbresponse[0].errors);
                if( $scope.dbresponse[0].messages[0] != null){
                    console.log("success message");

                    console.log("After Setting it");
                }else if ($scope.dbresponse[0].errors != null){
                    console.log("has errors throw validation message");
                }
         }).error(function(error){
                alert("Please Try again");
                });
```

This is My repsonse as seen on Console

```
    Object    
    errors:null
    messages:Array[1] 
           0:Added Successfully
```

What i want to do is access that message and populate on the front end .I'm using ng-repeat to do and its failing.

this is my HTML

```
     <table>
<tr ng-repeat="messages in dbresponse.messages">
<td align="left" class="validMsg"><img src="images/red_bullet.gif" border="0" width="8" height="8" alt="">&nbsp;{{messages}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your API call response it seems your 'dbresponse' is an array:

> console.log($scope.dbresponse[0].messages);

Whereas in your html you access it as a single object with properties:

> <tr ng-repeat="messages in dbresponse.messages">

If your 'responseData' is an array you might want to treat it as such in your html. If it is not the case, please supply a bit more information on what the html looks like and what the '$scope' contains.

Comment: Hey Filipe ,It was a Typo . I am trying using ng-repeat like this only
 <tr ng-repeat="messages in dbresponse[0].messages" >.I am populating scope like this  $scope.dbresponse = responseData; .The contents of the scope, i have posted it along with the Question